# "Ein Foto nehmen" und "Take a photo": verständlich, idomatisch?

Tags: translation, english-to-german

> I can take a photo for you.

Eine vom [Wörterbuch](http://dictionary.reverso.net/german-english/foto) vorgeschlagene Übersetzung:

> Ich kann ein Foto für dich machen.

Wäre die direkte Übersetzung

> Ich kann ein Foto für dich **nehmen**.

völlig falsch? Wie würde man das verstehen?

Comment: Related: [What is a better verb for “Fotos machen”?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/2651/what-is-a-better-verb-for-fotos-machen)

Comment: Same with *auf*nehmen, take care!

Comment: @bobbee: "aufnehmen" is fine for photos!

Comment: @Stephie you have to be careful because it can also mean picking something up.

Comment: @bobbee: But it *can* also mean take a picture, "nehmen" *can't*.

Comment: "ein Foto nehmen" ist Englisch mit deutschen Wörtern, aber kein idiomatisches Deutsch. Der übliche Ausdruck ist "ein Foto machen".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct translation is **"für jemanden ein Foto machen"**.

The second suggestion may well be understood by native German speakers as it is a relatively common mistake, but at first glance it seems to suggest:

> "I can grab a picture for you (i.e. from a stack of photographs)."

[Sample sentences of Foto + nehmen in context](http://www.linguee.com/german-english/translation/foto+nehmen.html)

Comment: It might be understood by Germans with *some knowledge of english*.

Comment: @Stephie or Germans with some knowledge of other languages which use the verb "to take" in the context of photographing (i.e. Spanish, Japanese, etc.)

Comment: The translation examples that are given in the Linguee link are funny to read, since most of them are clearly wrong. So just don't say "ein Foto nehmen" in German, since it is wrong.

Comment: @Rolland Illig I was attempting to give an example of the way the verb nehmen is actuallly used with the noun Foto in German, although you are right to point out that some of the listed excerpts are incorrect (i.e., the Brazilian tourist website). Still, a majority of the excerpts demonstrate the point of my answer: you only use "nehmen" with the noun Foto in German when you are physically (or with software) grabbing and/or utilizing a photograph, not "snapping" one.

Answer (score 4):

> Ich kann ein Foto für dich nehmen.

Bedeutet physisch ein Foto zu greifen und an den Angesprochenen zu geben.

Fotos in Deinem Kontext werden im Deutschen "gemacht". (oder, im Slang, "geknipst" bzw. "geschossen")

Comment: Wait. Why is it a false friend? It's not a friend to begin with. It sounds like the sentence with "nehmen" is common, which it is not. I find it extremely weird and wouldn't know where to use it. If we call this one a false friend, any literal translation that doesn't work is a false friend.

Comment: Wie wär's mit *aufnehmen*, *Aufnahme machen*, ?

Comment: @Takkat: aufnehmen ist was anderes als nehmen, genau wie beispielsweise unternehmen.

Comment: @falkb: eben. Aufnahme syn. Fotografie, aufnehmen syn. fotografieren - auch wir nehmen das nehmen, wenn auch mit auf.

Comment: Wobei ich "aufnehmen" eher mit Videos assoziieren würde, weniger mit Fotos