# Welches Verb passt zum Wort «Selfie»?

Tags: grammar, verb, verb-usage

> Ich nehme ein Selfie mit meiner Freundin auf.
>
> Ich mache ein Selfie.

Kann man die beiden Verben in diesem Kontext verwenden?

Comment: `Ich fotographiere mich` ... Konnts mir nicht verkneifen.

Comment: Related: [What is a better verb for “Fotos machen”?](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/2651/9551) and [“Ein Foto nehmen” und “Take a photo”: verständlich, idomatisch?](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/18672/9551)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ein Selfie ist ein Foto oder ein Bild. Man kann dafür alle Verben benutzen, die man auch mit *ein Foto* statt *ein Selfie* kombinieren kann:

> Ein Selfie schießen
>   Ein Selfie aufnehmen
>   Ein Selfie machen
>   Ein Selfie knipsen
>   …

Answer (score 4):

Angesichts der Jargonhaftigkeit des Begriffs "Selfie" würde ich "Ich nehme ein Selfie auf" für gestelzt halten. Daher "Ich mache ein Selfie" oder "Ich schieße ein Selfie".  - Auf keinen Fall natürlich "Kannste mal ein Selfie von mir machen?" ;)

Comment: Wie wärs mit Gruppenselfie?

Answer (score 2):

Ein Selfie bezieht sich vielleicht auf den Gebrauch von Smartphones oder Komapaktkameras.
Es ist ja eine Kompaktkamera im mobilen Telefon verbaut. Also wie fotografieren, Bild aufnehmen, Foto schießen, Selbstportrait machen (modus), Bild knipsen.

Deshalb könnte man auch den Ausdruck formulieren:

> Wir machen ein Selfie.
>   Ich knipse ein Selfie.
>   Wir nehmen ein Selfie auf.
>   Ein Selfie schießen.

etc.

Comment: Ein Selfie fotografieren bedeutet, ein Foto von einem Selfie zu machen.

Comment: korrigiert und überlege ob es noch weitere gibt.